# access firefox about:config property from a web page

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-plugin

It's possibile to access (in read-only mode) to a value stored in a "about:config" property from an "unprivilegied" (as in: loaded from a http:// ... /something.html) script?

More specifically, I see the next ff (19?) will enable by default the "feature" click-to-play (see [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/01/29/putting-users-in-control-of-plugins) for a description).

Is there a way, programmatically, to know in advance if the flag is true on the browser? We use a custom plugin and need to handle a custom "popup" to instruct the users about the feature and how to whitelist. And no, my users aren't savy enough to recognize the default ff "blocked plugin" logo in the upper right corner of the address bar)

Comment: I sure do hope it's not possible.

Comment: I'll bet this is'nt possible, as it would be considered a security risk if it was.

Comment: while I understand a "generic" access to all the local user config is a major security corncern, is there a way to access specifically this voice?It's a big change in how plugin interact with web pages.

Comment: Note that the blog entry doesn't say which version this will be implemented in. This definitely won't happen for Fx19, as that one is already in beta.

Answer (score 1):

This is not accessible from non-chrome code. Even if it was (say from a extension), you shouldn't depend on it as this may not be the setting that triggers the planned changes.

You can differentiate between the plugin not being installed (see `navigator.plugins`) and other cases by either

- regularly testing it's scriptability or
- having the plugin call into the pages script when it is loaded

... and assume *"failed to load or got blocked"* based on that.